# Searching for a term

Tags: grammaire, terminologie, demande-de-mot

[image]

Is there a specific name for this phenomenon? I guess 'jeux des mots' or 'bizarreries' are not appropriate terms for a grammar book:-)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ce sont des homographes. Les mots s'écrivent de la même façon mais la prononciation peut être différente.  Cela fait partie de la catégorie des homonymes.

> Un [homographe](http://stella.atilf.fr/Dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/advanced.exe?8;s=1219975080;) LING. (Mot) dont la graphie est identique à celle d'un
> autre mot.

En particulier, ce sont des homographes non homophones comme @Greg a bien souligné.  Il y a aussi des homographes homophones (qui se prononcent de la même manière).

Les phrases comme ça montrent la différence de prononciation.  On s'amuse bien avec.

De [Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homographe) :

- Ces cuisiniers excellent à composer cet excellent plat.
- Nous nous oignons de purée d'oignons.
- Ces dames se parent de fleurs pour leur parent.
- Tu as un as dans ton jeu.

Comment: Je dirais même plus: ce sont des homographes non homophones (par opposition à des homographes homophones, comme p.ex."vers" dans "les vers rampent vers la terre")

Comment: @Greg Tout à fait, beaucoup d'enjeux des « vers » dans la domaine de l'homonymie !